# knockout mapping fromJS fromJSON isn't working inside a collection?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've got my root knockout model that holds a collection of VisitEntries, each of these entries has an object on it called RoomProfile. When a user creates a visit entry (adds a room to their visit list), the room's profile data should be loaded and displayed to the user inside that collection. But I can't update the associated model. I've done this before in other areas no problem. I think there is a problem because I am making a copy of `VisitEntryToAdd` on my root `mappedModel`, or because it's inside a collection. I'm not sure, but those are the only differences from other times when I've done this.

```
mappedModel.addVisitEntry = function () {

        var visitEntryToAdd = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(mappedModel.VisitEntryToAdd));

        $.ajax({
            url: '/GetRoomProfileForVisit',
            type: 'POST',
            data: ko.mapping.toJSON({ Id: visitEntryToAdd.SelectedRoom.Id() }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {

                if (data !== null) {
                    console.log("Checking entry before assigning room profile data: \n" + ko.mapping.toJSON(visitEntryToAdd));
                    console.log("Room Profile Data Loaded:\n" + ko.mapping.toJSON(data));
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, visitEntryToAdd.RoomProfile);
                    console.log("Checking entry after assigning room profile data: \n" + ko.mapping.toJSON(visitEntryToAdd));
                }

                mappedModel.VisitEntries.push(visitEntryToAdd);

            }
        });
    }
```

Going through the above code:

First console.log shows that `visitEntryToAdd` has all the correct fields including `RoomProfile` which it set to null before I add the room profile data.

Second console.log confirms my ajax method did return data and it is appropriately formed.

Third console.log shows that same `visitEntryToAdd`, and `RoomProfile` on it is still null.

I was able to get this working by doing:

```
visitEntryToAdd.RoomProfile(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
```

But I am not sure why it doesn't work using the `fromJS` command only, as that it's usage. If someone can provide an explanation I will mark that as the answer.

Comment: Is this a mistake: you are console.logging some `labVisitEntryToAdd` which isn't defined in your code sample?

Comment: Abstraction mistake when copying.

Comment: Please try to make a [mcve] by stubbing out the Ajax code if possible, and including enough (but as little as possible) example data, as well as view model code for context / to make things runnable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `visitEntryToAdd.RoomProfile` is null before the mapping, you are effectively saying `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, null)` and there is nothing tying the newly mapped data to the viewmodel.

You can solve this by initializing `RoomProfile` on the visit entry to `{}` instead of `null`, or executing the mapping as:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS({RoomProfile: data}, {}, visitEntryToAdd);
```

This way mapping will begin from the root of the viewmodel and the `RoomProfile` field on it is assignable. If it makes sense to initialize the field to `{}` instead, it will work because the `RoomProfile` field on the viewmodel is not replaced, only fields on it are updated and so the link from visitEntryToAdd -> RoomProfile is preserved.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. I feel better using this then the way I figured out in my post.